# Is it possible to deduce the argument types of a functor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, functor, type-deduction

Is it possible to deduce the argument types of a functor? For example:

```
struct foo {
    int operator()(double, std::string const&) const { return 0; }
};

template<class Foo>
struct bar
{
    using first_argument_type = /* type of the first argument of Foo::operator() */;
    using second_argument_type = /* type of the second argument of Foo::operator() */;
    using return_type = std::result_of_t<Foo(first_argument_type, second_argument_type)>;
};
```

Comment: Please assume that we know that `foo` has exactly two arguments and that there is no overload of `operator()`.

Comment: Except if there are overloads, you can use some *function_traits*.

Comment: See e.g. the [CallableTraits library](https://github.com/badair/callable_traits).